# A Question on a continuous function and limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

I'm wondering that if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous at $x_0\in[a,b]$ then
$$
\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}f(x)dx}{h} = f(x_0) ?
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: @Thorgott But denominator also tends to $0$

Comment: @DHMO I'm proving Fundamental theorem of calculus for Lebesgue integral

Comment: You need more hypotheses on $f,$ like it's measurable or something.

Comment: @zhw thanks I changed my question. since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ I think it is borel measurable

Comment: You could just say $f$ is Lebesgue measurable on an interval $(a,b)$ with $f$ continuous at $x_0\in (a,b)$. Then $f$ is bounded near $x_0$ hence is integrable on some $(x_0-\delta,x_0+ \delta)$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then $\exists \delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|=|h|<\delta$ then  $|f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)|=|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$

Thus  $|\frac{\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}f(x)}{h}-f(x_0)|=|\frac{\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}f(x)dx-\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}f(x_0)dx}{h}| \leqslant \frac{\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}\epsilon dx}{h}=\epsilon$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon>0$, we have, for $h$ small enough:

$$f(x_0)-\epsilon<f(x)<f(x_0)+\epsilon$$

for $x$ between $x_0$ and $x_0+h$. This is because $f$ is continuous.

So $$\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h} f(x)\,dx$$ is between $h(f(x_0)+\epsilon)$ and $h(f(x_0)-\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\int f(x)dx = F(x) \implies F'(x)=f(x) \tag 1$$

Your question is :

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}f(x)dx}{h} =\lim_{h\to0} \frac{F(x_0+h)-F(x_0)}{h}=F'(x_0)$$

Using $(1)$ :$$F'(x_0)=f(x_0)$$

Comment: OP is trying to prove this, so you've just proven it by assertion.

Comment: This is circular.

Comment: @Ian, can you explain why it is circular?

Comment: To be specific, this is circular because the relationship between integration and antidifferentiation is exactly what is to be proven here.